# MySQL Syntax Error, Can't Figure it Out

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I have the following MySQL statement to insert a lot of data into a lot of columns in a table:

```
INSERT INTO survey (lang,check,lname,fname,age,dob,dlang1,dlang2,dlang3,dlang4,dlang5,alang1,alang2,alang3,alang4,alang5,expperc1,expperc2,expperc3,expperc4,expperc5,readperc1,readperc2,readperc3,readperc4,readperc5,speakperc1,speakperc2,speakperc3,speakperc4,speakperc5,culture1,culture2,culture3,culture4,culture5,eduyears,eduother,immi, ...
```

I get the following error when I try to run the statement:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '"INSERT INTO survey
>   (lang,check,lname,fname,age,dob,dlang1,dlang2,dlang3,dlang4,' at line
>   1

I thought that to insert data into specific columns I'm supposed to list out all of the column names in ()s, as I've done. Am I missing something here?

For reference, here's the full statement, although the syntax error should have been reached before most of this, right?

```
INSERT INTO survey (lang,check,lname,fname,age,dob,dlang1,dlang2,dlang3,dlang4,dlang5,alang1,alang2,alang3,alang4,alang5,expperc1,expperc2,expperc3,expperc4,expperc5,readperc1,readperc2,readperc3,readperc4,readperc5,speakperc1,speakperc2,speakperc3,speakperc4,speakperc5,culture1,culture2,culture3,culture4,culture5,eduyears,eduother,immi,emi,correction,level1,ageacq1,agefluent1,ageread1,agereadf1,ycountry1,mcountry1,yfamily1,mfamily1,yschool1,mschool1,speak1,understand1,read1,learnfriends1,learntapes1,learnfamily1,learntv1,learnread1,learnradio1,expofriends1,exporadio1,expofamily1,exporead1,expotv1,expotapes1,accent1,level2,ageacq2,agefluent2,ageread2,agereadf2,ycountry2,mcountry2,yfamily2,mfamily2,yschool2,mschool2,speak2,understand2,read2,learnfriends2,learntapes2,learnfamily2,learntv2,learnread2,learnradio2,expofriends2,exporadio2,expofamily2,exporead2,expotv2,expotapes2,accent2,comb_str,comb_time,wrench_str,wrench_time,snowman_str,snowman_time,raccoon_str,raccoon_time,watch_str,watch_time,horse_str,horse_time,church_str,church_time,iron_str,iron_time,wateringcan_str,wateringcan_time,stroller_str,stroller_time,saw_str,saw_time,wolf_str,wolf_time,stove_str,stove_time,donkey_str,donkey_time,anchor_str,anchor_time,boot_str,boot_time,needle_str,needle_time,pillar_str,pillar_time,thimble_str,thimble_time,window_str,window_time,pencil_str,pencil_time,squirrel_str,squirrel_time,cup_str,cup_time,clothespin_str,clothespin_time,ball_str,ball_time,penguin_str,penguin_time,cow_str,cow_time,salt_str,salt_time,tiger_str,tiger_time,icecreamcone_str,icecreamcone_time,sink_str,sink_time,spider_str,spider_time,cloud_str,cloud_time,fan_str,fan_time,tweezers_str,tweezers_time,pen_str,pen_time,ant_str,ant_time,caterpillar_str,caterpillar_time,spoon_str,spoon_time,pipe_str,pipe_time,snake_str,snake_time,lips_str,lips_time,sword_str,sword_time,palmtree_str,palmtree_time,barn_str,barn_time,orange_str,orange_time,cat_str,cat_time,flower_str,flower_time,apple_str,apple_time,wood_str,wood_time,grasshopper_str,grasshopper_time,leopard_str,leopard_time,lightswitch_str,lightswitch_time,onion_str,onion_time,washingmachine_str,washingmachine_time,nose_str,nose_time,seahorse_str,seahorse_time,windmill_str,windmill_time,sun_str,sun_time,toothbrush_str,toothbrush_time,ruler_str,ruler_time,boat_str,boat_time,elephant_str,elephant_time,crab_str,crab_time,bug_str,bug_time,monkey_str,monkey_time,rope_str,rope_time,heart_str,heart_time,fish_str,fish_time,plug_str,plug_time,jacket_str,jacket_time,helicopter_str,helicopter_time,rhinoceros_str,rhinoceros_time,corkscrew_str,corkscrew_time,envelope_str,envelope_time,wagon_str,wagon_time,belt_str,belt_time,antlers_str,antlers_time,stocking_str,stocking_time,saltshaker_str,saltshaker_time,car_str,car_time,refrigerator_str,refrigerator_time,airplane_str,airplane_time,pig_str,pig_time,cherry_str,cherry_time,circle_str,circle_time,stool_str,stool_time,gun_str,gun_time,balloon_str,balloon_time,crib_str,crib_time,vest_str,vest_time,snail_str,snail_time,hippo_str,hippo_time,tennisracket_str,tennisracket_time,fence_str,fence_time,gorilla_str,gorilla_time,bear_str,bear_time,chest_str,chest_time,brush_str,brush_time,ostrich_str,ostrich_time,priest_str,priest_time,mountain_str,mountain_time,x_str,x_time,chisel_str,chisel_time,bed_str,bed_time,eye_str,eye_time,basket_str,basket_time,asparagus_str,asparagus_time,scissors_str,scissors_time,couch_str,couch_time,flashlight_str,flashlight_time,box_str,box_time,grave_str,grave_time,watermelon_str,watermelon_time,knife_str,knife_time,leg_str,leg_time,blouse_str,blouse_time,violin_str,violin_time,rock_str,rock_time,tomato_str,tomato_time,parachute_str,parachute_time,dustpan_str,dustpan_time,vase_str,vase_time,sewingmachine_str,sewingmachine_time,house_str,house_time,backpack_str,backpack_time,door_str,door_time,diaper_str,diaper_time,curtains_str,curtains_time,nail_str,nail_time,bowl_str,bowl_time,dresser_str,dresser_time,butterfly_str,butterfly_time,ladle_str,ladle_time,toaster_str,toaster_time,leaf_str,leaf_time,cannon_str,cannon_time,square_str,square_time,whistle_str,whistle_time,triangle_str,triangle_time,glasses_str,glasses_time,skateboard_str,skateboard_time,skunk_str,skunk_time,clown_str,clown_time,dime_str,dime_time,grapes_str,grapes_time,ironingboard_str,ironingboard_time,closet_str,closet_time,safetypin_str,safetypin_time,hair_str,hair_time,shirt_str,shirt_time,rollingpin_str,rollingpin_time,bell_str,bell_time,gas_str,gas_time,hook_str,hook_time,glass_str,glass_time,bucket_str,bucket_time,worm_str,worm_time,top_str,top_time,garbage_can_str,garbage_can_time,barrel_str,barrel_time,strawberry_str,strawberry_time,well_str,well_time,ax_str,ax_time,seal_str,seal_time,necklace_str,necklace_time,cake_str,cake_time,ring_str,ring_time,genie_str,genie_time,beard_str,beard_time,pitcher_str,pitcher_time,pear_str,pear_time,tape_str,tape_time,pliers_str,pliers_time,giraffe_str,giraffe_time,train_str,train_time,owl_str,owl_time,celery_str,celery_time,wheel_str,wheel_time,bricks_str,bricks_time,skirt_str,skirt_time,truck_str,truck_time,clock_str,clock_time,bicycle_str,bicycle_time,egg_str,egg_time,kettle_str,kettle_time,shoe_str,shoe_time,lettuce_str,lettuce_time,lawnmower_str,lawnmower_time,tent_str,tent_time,tie_str,tie_time,table_str,table_time,lemon_str,lemon_time,wheelchair_str,wheelchair_time,scale_str,scale_time,peacock_str,peacock_time,frying_pan_str,frying_pan_time,spiderweb_str,spiderweb_time,broom_str,broom_time,tear_str,tear_time,screwdriver_str,screwdriver_time,sled_str,sled_time,arm_str,arm_time,peach_str,peach_time,lock_str,lock_time,bread_str,bread_time,thumb_str,thumb_time,chicken_str,chicken_time,teapot_str,teapot_time,fishingpole_str,fishingpole_time,football_str,football_time,deer_str,deer_time,turtle_str,turtle_time,pumpkin_str,pumpkin_time,peas_str,peas_time,zebra_str,zebra_time,paintbrush_str,paintbrush_time,chain_str,chain_time,eskimo_str,eskimo_time,rollerskate_str,rollerskate_time,peanut_str,peanut_time,vacuum_str,vacuum_time,football_helmet_str,football_helmet_time,cactus_str,cactus_time,doorknob_str,doorknob_time,tv_str,tv_time,sailboat_str,sailboat_time,piano_str,piano_time,suitcase_str,suitcase_time,mosquito_str,mosquito_time,lipstick_str,lipstick_time,nut_str,nut_time,purse_str,purse_time,sandwich_str,sandwich_time,mitten_str,mitten_time,kangaroo_str,kangaroo_time,crown_str,crown_time,flag_str,flag_time,button_str,button_time,cigarette_str,cigarette_time,baseball_bat_str,baseball_bat_time,ghost_str,ghost_time,turkey_str,turkey_time,hammer_str,hammer_time,saddle_str,saddle_time,bird_str,bird_time,fork_str,fork_time,hand_str,hand_time,mixer_str,mixer_time,recordplayer_str,recordplayer_time,swan_str,swan_time,rockingchair_str,rockingchair_time,mask_str,mask_time,guitar_str,guitar_time,fly_str,fly_time,duck_str,duck_time,floor_str,floor_time,bottle_str,bottle_time,hat_str,hat_time,fox_str,fox_time,camel_str,camel_time,net_str,net_time,typewriter_str,typewriter_time,mushroom_str,mushroom_time,igloo_str,igloo_time,panda_str,panda_time,paint_str,paint_time,fishtank_str,fishtank_time,ladder_str,ladder_time,cigar_str,cigar_time,artichoke_str,artichoke_time,hanger_str,hanger_time,flute_str,flute_time,telephone_str,telephone_time,policeman_str,policeman_time,key_str,key_time,carrot_str,carrot_time,pot_str,pot_time,potato_str,potato_time,zipper_str,zipper_time,pants_str,pants_time,bone_str,bone_time,fire_str,fire_time,ear_str,ear_time,toilet_str,toilet_time,doll_str,doll_time,pineapple_str,pineapple_time,lion_str,lion_time,binoculars_str,binoculars_time,hamburger_str,hamburger_time,walnut_str,walnut_time,camera_str,camera_time,chair_str,chair_time,ashtray_str,ashtray_time,bee_str,bee_time,umbrella_str,umbrella_time,globe_str,globe_time,harp_str,harp_time,motorcycle_str,motorcycle_time,lobster_str,lobster_time,sock_str,sock_time,slide_str,slide_time,alligator_str,alligator_time,rabbit_str,rabbit_time,block_str,block_time,arrow_str,arrow_time,banana_str,banana_time,crackers_str,crackers_time,sheep_str,sheep_time,thread_str,thread_time,puzzle_str,puzzle_time,sweater_str,sweater_time,radish_str,radish_time,porcupine_str,porcupine_time,foot_str,foot_time,bus_str,bus_time,lamp_str,lamp_time,kite_str,kite_time,desk_str,desk_time,trumpet_str,trumpet_time,rake_str,rake_time,canopener_str,canopener_time,wheat_str,wheat_time,railroadtracks_str,railroadtracks_time,lightbulb_str,lightbulb_time,finger_str,finger_time,tree_str,tree_time,trash_str,trash_time,goat_str,goat_time,star_str,star_time,glove_str,glove_time,swing_str,swing_time,moon_str,moon_time,mouse_str,mouse_time,waffle_str,waffle_time,screw_str,screw_time,eagle_str,eagle_time,dog_str,dog_time,corn_str,corn_time,toe_str,toe_time,coat_str,coat_time,stoplight_str,stoplight_time,road_str,road_time,frog_str,frog_time,earring_str,earring_time,rooster_str,rooster_time,music_str,music_time,book_str,book_time,candle_str,candle_time,drum_str,drum_time) 
VALUES ("0","on","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","2228","","518","","37","","36","","37","","39","","35","","37","","37","","36","","44","","30","","37","","37","","37","","41","","32","","37","","47","","27","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","41","","33","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","38","","36","","38","","36","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","39","","35","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","38","","36","","39","","35","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","39","","35","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","39","","35","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","46","","27","","37","","39","","35","","37","","36","","38","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","39","","35","","36","","38","","36","","36","","37","","39","","37","","35","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","38","","36","","37","","36","","38","","36","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","38","","36","","37","","39","","34","","37","","37","","37","","36","","52","","22","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","38","","36","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","39","","35","","37","","37","","37","","39","","35","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","39","","44","","28","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","38","","36","","36","","41","","33","","39","","36","","37","","37","","36","","36","","36","","37","","38","","36","","37","","37","","36","","40","","35","","37","","36","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","40","","35","","36","","43","","30","","39","","36","","36","","37","","36","","37","","49","","25","","37","","39","","36","","36","","40","","34","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","36","","39","","35","","37","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","36","","41","","35","","36","","37","","37","","36","","39","","36","","36","","37","","37","","36","","37","","37","","37","","37","","37","","45","","28","","37","","36","","37","","39")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check is reserved word, so put it backticks '\`'. But it's not your immediate problem because otherwise you'd see `...near 'check...` in the error message. Please show relevant parts of your client code where you compose and execute this query. Also you better put values in single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your error but: string (character) values should be enclosed in single quotes. Double quotes denote column names (at least if you are running in ANSI mode). And numbers should never be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error message your immediate problem is caused by fact that you have extra double quotes around your INSERT statement or at least at the begging right in front of `INSERT`

```
"INSERT INTO survey (lang,check,lname,fname,age,dob,dlang1,dlang2,dlang3,dlang4,
^^
```

Other than that `check` is a reserved word in MySQL, so put it in backticks '`'.

Also you better put values in single quotes rather than double quotes.

That being said your INSERT statement should rather look like

```
INSERT INTO survey (lang,`check`,lname,...) VALUES ('0','on','',...)
^                        ^     ^                    ^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
```

Comment: If `lang` is a numeric column, the value should not be put in single quotes either. Numbers don't need quotes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In general I agree. But in MySQL it doesn't hurt at all to put numeric values into single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware check was a reserved word in MySQL!

Answer (score 0):

Please quote all columns name. see exp below

```
INSERT INTO survey (`lang`,`check`,`lname`,`fname`,`age`,`dob`...
```